# java code merge two listed llink arrays and order it in decreasing order to new array

Tags: java, arrays, string, merge, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to have the user input integers for first linked list and second linked list then merge them into a new array in decreasing order. The problem is when it print out the result it identify two digits number as one number and ordering it wrong.

Example:

```
enter first sentence:
1 8 0 4
enter second sentence:
3 2 9 10
result:
9 8 4 3 2 10 1 0
```

The problem is
it counted 10 as 1

The desired result

```
10 9 8 4 3 2 1 0
```

Here my codes and classes

```java
package homework;

import static homework.Cipher.decode;
import static homework.Cipher.encode;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HOMEWORK {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        while (x != 5) {
            System.out.println("-_-_-_-_-MENU-_-_-_-_-\n1-Encrypt Text"
                    + "\n2-Decrypt Text"
                    + "\n3-Merge two sorted list in decreasing order"
                    + "\n4- Reverse Linked List Recursively "
                    + "\n5- Exit ");
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");
            x = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            switch (x) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter Line to encode: ");
                    String plaintext = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter Shift  Number:");
                    int number = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();

                    String encoded = encode(plaintext, number);
                    System.out.println("Result:");
                    System.out.println(encoded);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Please enter Line to decode: ");
                    String code = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter Shift  Number:");
                    int number1 = input.nextInt();
                    input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Result:");
                    System.out.println(decode(code, number1));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Merge list1 = new Merge();
                    Merge list2 = new Merge();
                    System.out.println("Enter first scentence :");
                    String[] string1 = input.nextLine().split(" ");

                    System.out.println("Enter second scentence :");
                    String[] string2 = input.nextLine().split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
                        list1.insert(string1[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
                        list2.insert(string2[i]);
                    }
                    Merge merged = list1.merge(list1, list2);

                    System.out.println("Result ");
                    merged.Display();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    SinglyLinkedList LL = new SinglyLinkedList();
                    System.out.println("Enter  scentence to reverse :");
                    String[] string = input.nextLine().split(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                        LL.addLast(string[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("REVERSED");
                    System.out.println(LL.reverse());
                    break;
                case 5:
                default:
                    System.out.println(" Goodbye ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Merge` class

```
package homework;

public class Merge {
    public Node head = null; // head node of the list (or null if empty) 
    // access methods 
    int size = 0;

// update methods 
    public void addFirst(String e) { // adds data e to the front of the list 
        head = new Node(e, head);// create and link a new node 
        size++;
    }

    public String deleteFirst() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        String remo = head.element;
        head = head.next;
        size--;
        return remo;
    }

    public void insert(String element) {
        if (head == null || head.element.compareTo(element) >= 0) {
            addFirst(element);
        } else {
            Node p = head;
            Node c = p.next;
            while (c != null && c.element.compareTo(element) <= 0) {
                p = c;
                c = c.next;
            }
            Node newest = new Node(element, c); // node will eventually be the tail 
            p.next = newest;
        }
    }

    public void Display() {
        Node N = head;
        while (N != null) {
            System.out.print(N.element + " ");
            N = N.next;
        }
    }

    public Merge merge(Merge list1, Merge list2) {
        Merge merged = new Merge();
        Node head1 = list1.head;
        Node head2 = list2.head;
        if (head1 == null) {
            return list2;
        }
        if (head2 == null) {
            return list1;
        }
        merged.head = null;
        if (head1.element.compareTo(head2.element) <= 0) {
            merged.head = head1;
            head1 = head1.next;
        } else {
            merged.head = head2;
            head2 = head2.next;
        }
        Node mergedTail = merged.head;
        while (head1 != null && head2 != null) {
            Node temp = null;
            if (head1.element.compareTo(head2.element) <= 0) {
                temp = head1;
                head1 = head1.next;
            } else {
                temp = head2;
                head2 = head2.next;
            }
            mergedTail.next = temp;
            mergedTail = temp;
        }
        if (head1 != null) {
            mergedTail.next = head1;
        } else if (head2 != null) {
            mergedTail.next = head2;
        }
        Node p = null;
        Node c = merged.head;
        Node next = null;
        while (c != null) {
            next = c.next;
            c.next = p;
            p = c;
            c = next;
        }
        merged.head = p;
        return merged;
    }

    public static class Node {
        private String element;
        private Node next;

// reference to the data stored at this node // reference to the subsequent node in the list
        public Node(String e, Node n) {
            element = e;
            next = n;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change them into integers instead of a string but it won't work and only give me errors everywhere.

Comment: _I tried to change them into integers instead of a string but it won't work and only give me errors everywhere._ Then you need to [edit] your question and post that code, as well as details of the errors you are getting. I easily changed the `String` to `Integer` and the code in your question produced the expected result.

Comment: Strings don't sort the same as integers.  You will need to change to integers to get this to work.  Please show the code you are having problems with, this code sorts (strings) correctly.

Comment: a quick fix is to parse whatever int you want out from the string before doing any sort of comparison using Integer.parseInt(). Though the more logical answer would be to use Integer wrapper class from the start (it supports compareTo()), or you could just use an int, and use an equality operator instead

Answer (score 0):

Return is correct:

```
3 2 9 10 =>  9     3 2 10  
1 8 0 4  =>    8 4        1 0
result:      9 8 4 3 2 10 1 0
```

Just missing the sorting